# Authenticated encryption using libsodium's crypto_box_curve25519xsalsa20poly1305

Tags: public-key, libsodium, xsalsa20

It seems that `crypto_box_easy`, generates a random nonce and appends it to the cipher text in libsodium.

I understand **using the same nonce** with the **same key** can be **catastrophic** with  `salsa20poly1305`, as such is it bad practice to re-use the same public/private (static) `curve25519` keys when using crypto_box_easy?

Is it safe enough to assume that libsodium will ensure a random nonce is always used, or should `curve25519` keypairs be regenerated on each use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`crypto_box_easy()` doesn't generate a random nonce. But as [documented](https://download.libsodium.org/doc/public-key_cryptography/authenticated_encryption), using a random nonce is safe, and can be done using `randombytes_buf(nonce, sizeof nonce);`. It's still the application's responsibility to include that nonce in the payload.

Alternatively, the more recent [secretstream](https://download.libsodium.org/doc/secret-key_cryptography/secretstream) API automatically creates and attaches a nonce, and can encrypt a sequence of messages without having to care about the nonce at all.

(that being said, this is a programming question, so cryptography.stackexchange may not be the best place for it)

Comment: Ah my confusion was in part due to Swift-Sodium, in that authenticated public key boxes (crypto_box_easy), are provided a random nonce in the call self.nonce() - I guess in the c lib one must do this manually. I am working to understand this so that I can write up some documentation for Swift-Sodium. So in closing, it's safe to reuse public/private key pairs more than once, assuming a random nonce is used, as it is in swift-sodium?

Comment: Yes, a key can be reused as long as a `(key, nonce)` tuple is not reused. Swift-sodium does that automatically, and intentionally hides internal implementation details, including in the documentation. Users are not even expected to know what a nonce is. Ultimately, the Swift-sodium API should work with libhydrogen/libsodium2 with no changes.

Comment: Yup makes sense, I am trying to understand all of these things in detail so I can write good quality docs for Swift-Sodium. Why do are you aiming to make swift-sodium so easy to use? The user in C must generate his own nonce, why make it easy for the swift dev? -- Or maybe the better question is, why not include a random nonce as part of crypto_box_easy, ensuring safer use in C... Folks will probably regularly re-use key pairs generated in apps, because pub/priv key pairs tend to be swapped. So it's safer to provide an automatic random nonce in the implementation I think.

Comment: Backward compatibility. The C libsodium API cannot be changed at this point. The Swift wrappers are more recent and didn't have the same constraints. In libhydrogen, nonces are automatically generated and included, and the `box` API is gone.

Comment: Thanks @FrankDenis, makes sense :+1